# tcollector not collecting data. TSDB is empty

Tags: java, logging, hbase, monitoring, opentsdb

I successfully installed and its up and running at

```
http://54.72.4.157:4242/
```

I am running tcollector in one of our servers, and I did set the host in startstop.sh

```
TSD_HOST=54.72.4.157
```

i did

```
./startstop start
```

to run all the stats collector. Even noticed that in tsdb console log

```
[id: 0x5fc4bb31, /54.184.79.13:60203 => /172.31.14.125:4242] CONNECTED: /54.184.79.13:60203
```

On my tcollector node I did,

```
ps axl | grep tcollector
```

and I can see

```
0     0 16796 16795  20   0 183712  8000 poll_s Sl   ?          2:17 /usr/bin/python /home/mithralaya/tcollector/tcollector.py -c /home/mithralaya/tcollector/collectors -H 54.72.4.157 -t host=ip-172-31-12-203 -P /var/run/tcollector.pid
4 65534 16806 16796  20   0  39864  3748 poll_s Ss   ?          0:08 /usr/bin/python /home/mithralaya/tcollector/collectors/0/procstats.py
4 65534 16808 16796  39  19  39700  3380 poll_s SNs  ?          0:07 /usr/bin/python /home/mithralaya/tcollector/collectors/0/procnettcp.py
4 65534 16816 16796  20   0  39648  3240 poll_s Ss   ?          0:00 /usr/bin/python /home/mithralaya/tcollector/collectors/0/iostat.py
4 65534 16818 16796  20   0  39648  3400 poll_s Ss   ?          0:01 /usr/bin/python /home/mithralaya/tcollector/collectors/0/ifstat.py
4 65534 16822 16796  20   0  41848  3676 poll_s Ss   ?          0:05 /usr/bin/python /home/mithralaya/tcollector/collectors/0/netstat.py
4 65534 16824 16796  20   0  39648  3524 poll_s Ss   ?          0:00 /usr/bin/python /home/mithralaya/tcollector/collectors/0/dfstat.py
0     0 26617 26171  20   0   8108   940 pipe_w S+   pts/0      0:00 grep --color=auto tcollector
```

I cant see any significant errors in tcollector log on /var/log/tcollector. Latest log

```
2014-04-15 08:59:40,630 tcollector[16796] WARNING: haproxy.py: Error: HAProxy is not running
2014-04-15 08:59:55,090 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing redis-stats.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,091 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing nfsstat.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,091 tcollector[16796] WARNING: collector hbase_master.py terminated after 16 seconds with status code 1, marking dead
2014-04-15 08:59:55,091 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing udp_bridge.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,091 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing elasticsearch.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,092 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing zfsiostats.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,092 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing varnishstat.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,092 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing mongo.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,093 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing couchbase.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,093 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing graphite_bridge.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,093 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing zfskernstats.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,094 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing smart-stats.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,094 tcollector[16796] WARNING: collector mysql.py terminated after 16 seconds with status code 1, marking dead
2014-04-15 08:59:55,094 tcollector[16796] WARNING: collector hbase_regionserver.py terminated after 16 seconds with status code 1, marking dead
2014-04-15 08:59:55,095 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing postgresql.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,095 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing haproxy.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,095 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing riak.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,095 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing zookeeper.py from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 08:59:55,096 tcollector[16796] INFO: removing opentsdb.sh from the list of collectors (by request)
2014-04-15 09:09:40,651 tcollector[16796] INFO: Heartbeat (6 collectors running)
2014-04-15 09:19:41,217 tcollector[16796] INFO: Heartbeat (6 collectors running)
2014-04-15 09:29:41,794 tcollector[16796] INFO: Heartbeat (6 collectors running)
2014-04-15 09:39:43,586 tcollector[16796] INFO: Heartbeat (6 collectors running)
```

But none of the stats are getting collected. In hbase both tsdb and tsdb-uid are empty.

```
hbase(main):002:0> scan 'tsdb'
ROW                                                          COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                                                                                      
0 row(s) in 0.2890 seconds

hbase(main):003:0>
```

You can see that in here too,

```
http://54.72.4.157:60010/
```

If someone could help me with this, will be much appreciated.

All Hadoop based technologies are very difficult to install and configure. It took me a week to get my head around this and I am running the tcollector for 24 hrs and still no data in TSDB.

Many thanks,

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

From the log file output it seems none of tcollector plugins are actually running.  They get spawned and are removed right after due to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably a couple of collectors were running like procstats.py (which collects base metrics like cpu, memory, etc) which I noticed was not in the error log.

You are not getting data to your hbase probably because your opentsdb config is set to the default of you requiring to create manually the metrics. If so, then you have to define the metrics yourself.

Instead, to create an auto created metrics, try and go to your opentsdb server and check the config and set the metrics creation to automatic.

Specifically, in /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf, set the parameter "tsd.core.auto_create_metrics" to true, then restart the opentsdb service.

Then check again your hbase to see if you can see data in 'tsdb-uid' for instance.

Answer (score 0):

please try to set conf file to automatically create metric

```
# --------- CORE ----------
# Whether or not to automatically create UIDs for new metric types, default
# is False
tsd.core.auto_create_metrics = true
```

Comment: which file name we have to add this line